# What are the special coins and notes used that honor the Olympics and the new Emperor called?

Tags: words, culture

I understand that some new Olympic and Imperial coins/notes are being introduced into general circulation. I just want to know what these special Olympic and new Emperor coin/notes would be called.

Comment: https://www.mof.go.jp/currency/coin/commemorative_coin/2020_olyparagames/20180223.html

Comment: and of course: https://www.mof.go.jp/currency/coin/commemorative_coin/emperors_enthronement/20190510.html

Comment: Are these coins in general circulation? Is there paper money involved?

Comment: I wanted to find out the collective term for both coins and notes.