# What term would be used for commemorative coins and notes collectively?

Tags: meaning, words

Would commemorative coins and notes collectively be known as メモリアル？to indicate a type of memorial? The special money printed and coined in honor of special occasions such as the Olympics and other national events.

Comment: Did you see something specific that would lead you to think that?

Comment: I asked this question awhile back and never received an answer on what commemorative coins and notes would be. I was thinking there would be a word for this special money.

Comment: @BJCUAI, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/what-are-the-special-coins-and-notes-used-that-honor-the-olympics-and-the-new-em this was my previous question. The same answer would be accepted.

Comment: @JACK if the question was previously closed, why did you open a new question?  When you edit a closed question, it is automatically put up for review to re-open.

Comment: @ajsmart, I was asked to clarify by a friend reviewing the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[記念貨幣](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A8%98%E5%BF%B5%E8%B2%A8%E5%B9%A3) would cover both coinage and paper money used for memorializing purposes. As shown on the linked Wikipedia page, 記念紙幣 can be used to specify paper currency.